i want to pass date from MainActivity to MondayFragment, i give date in the newInstance but i give null in the onViewCreated
companion object {
private const val ARG_DATE = "date"
    fun newInstance(date: String): MondayFragment {
        val fragment = MondayFragment()
        val args = Bundle().apply {
            putString(ARG_DATE, date)
        }
        fragment.arguments = args
        Log.d("MondayFragment", "Date passed to MondayFragment: $date")
        return fragment
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(

    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = FragmentMondayBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val date = arguments?.getString(ARG_DATE)
    if (date == null) {
        Log.e("MondayFragment", "Date argument is null")
    } else {
        Log.d("MondayFragment", "Date: $date")
    }

2024-05-09 16:33:07.441 23989-23989 MondayFragment          com.giorgi.testroom                  D  Date passed to MondayFragment: 06-05-2024
2024-05-09 16:33:07.537 23989-23989 MondayFragment          com.giorgi.testroom                  E  Date argument is null.
in the Logcat i give this messige
